# Convert two datetimes to timestamps and keep the larger one

Tags: oracle19c

I work with Oracle Database 19c and I would like to convert two datetimes (DD/MM/YY HH24:MM:SS) into timestamps and only keep the larger one.

I try several script for the conversion like this one :

```sql
SELECT 
CODE_ACT_PROD, 
LIB, 
CAST (DAT_CRE AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE_CRE_TIMESTAMP,
CAST (DAT_MOD AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE_MOD_TIMESTAMP
FROM ACTI
WHERE CODE_ACT_PROD
IN (
    SELECT CODE_ACT_PROD
    FROM ART_COM
    WHERE ETAT = 0
)
```

but the result is not what I want, the datetimes are not convert and I don't know how to keep the larger one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle does not have a `datetime` data type.  It has `date` which has a day and a time to the second.  And it has a `timestamp` which also has a day and a time to the second with optional fractional seconds and time zone. Converting a `date` to a `timestamp` would just add fractional seconds which were always 0.  Neither `date` nor `timestamp` data types have a format.  A `varchar2` would have a format.  If the columns are `date` data types, your code is syntactically valid.  I'm not sure how results you are getting differ from the results you want since you're not showing us your sample data or expected results and you're not telling us what you mean when you say that something isn't converted.

Assuming the two columns are actually of type `date`, your code appears to be fine and you just want to use the `greatest` function to get the latest date.  See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b4049ed38929bee08f8d0aa11626fe71)

```
with cte as (
  select sysdate dat_cr, sysdate + 1 dat_mod
    from dual
)
select cast(dat_cr as timestamp) ts_cr,
       cast(dat_mod as timestamp) ts_mod,
       cast( greatest( dat_cr, dat_mod ) as timestamp ) ts_greatest
  from cte;

TS_CR                           TS_MOD                          TS_GREATEST
02-SEP-21 08.25.38.000000 AM    03-SEP-21 08.25.38.000000 AM    03-SEP-21 08.25.38.000000 AM
```

Note that the conversion of the three timestamps to strings to be displayed to humans is controlled by your session's `nls_timestamp_format`.

If you want to handle `null` dates by returning whichever date is `not null`, you can use a `coalesce` and a `case` statement

```
with cte as (
  select sysdate dat_cr, sysdate + 1 dat_mod
    from dual
  union all
  select null, sysdate from dual
  union all
  select sysdate, null from dual
)
select cast(dat_cr as timestamp) ts_cr,
       cast(dat_mod as timestamp) ts_mod,
       cast( case when dat_cr is null or dat_mod is null
                  then coalesce( dat_mod, dat_cr )
                  else greatest( dat_cr, dat_mod ) 
               end
              as timestamp ) ts_greatest
  from cte;
```

See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ccd82c52d7fca902b241b4983046ae2e)

Comment: Ok thank you @mt0
It works but if DAT_MOD is null, it returns null ... Is there a way to return DAT_CRE if DAT_MOD is null?

Answer (score 3):

Use `GREATEST`:

```sql
SELECT CODE_ACT_PROD, 
       LIB, 
       CAST (DAT_CRE AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE_CRE_TIMESTAMP,
       CAST (DAT_MOD AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE_MOD_TIMESTAMP,
       CAST(GREATEST(DAT_CRE, DAT_MOD) AS TIMESTAMP) AS greatest_timestamp
FROM   ACTI
WHERE  CODE_ACT_PROD IN (
         SELECT CODE_ACT_PROD
         FROM   ART_COM
         WHERE  ETAT = 0
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE acti (
  code_act_prod INT,
  lib           INT,
  dat_cre       DATE,
  dat_mod       DATE
);

CREATE TABLE art_com (
  code_act_prod INT,
  etat          INT
);

INSERT INTO acti (code_act_prod, lib, dat_cre, dat_mod)
SELECT 1, 2, SYSDATE - 1, SYSDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4, TRUNC(SYSDATE), SYSDATE - 2 FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO art_com (code_act_prod, etat)
SELECT 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CODE_ACT_PROD | LIB | DATE_CRE_TIMESTAMP | DATE_MOD_TIMESTAMP | GREATEST_TIMESTAMP |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2 | 2021-09-01 08:38:21.000000 | 2021-09-02 08:38:21.000000 | 2021-09-02 08:38:21.000000 |
> | 3 | 4 | 2021-09-02 00:00:00.000000 | 2021-08-31 08:38:21.000000 | 2021-09-02 00:00:00.000000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8eb30c1c60d55e154daf7a9f0a6500e1)*